# React Native Android No such property - logger for class DefaultProjectDescriptor

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

I am developing my app using React Native and now when I open the android project in Android Studio, during gradle sync it is throwing this error:

---

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'MyApp'.

> No such property: logger for class: org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: logger for class: org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor

---

I tried installing yarn add react-native-unimodules but this won't resolve.

I am using NVM to used node version 14.17.3
Android gradle plugin version: 4.1.0
Gradle version: 6.8

Please help me resolving this as I am stuck on this since 2 days now.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Facing the same problem!

Comment: @AxelHolmberg I closed all the apps and fully shutdown my system and restarted it, solved this issue.

Comment: Hmm, might not be relevant to others, but updating Android gradle plugin to 4.2.2 and Gradle to 6.9.1 seemed to solve the issue for me.

P.S. You can update those in File > Project Structure > Project

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem I tried different node versions with nvm and also downgrade android studio but none worked for me. also, I tried installing node via homebrew. What I did was to start android studio using

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

The problem was that android studio couldn't find node so in this case starting with the above command fixed the problem for me and I used nvm

Comment: Worked for me with a slight variation as I'm using JetBrains Toolbox : ```open Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app/```

Comment: Upvoting because it worked for me, on M1 with arm64 Android Studio (no Rosetta), but I would prefer somebody address the issue why it cannot find node in the first place, when the node command is in my paths. Please and thank you to whoever can answer this.

Comment: The real fix is stackoverflow.com/a/70891538/9878385 Run `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by fully shutting down my MacBook Pro and starting it up again. Once started I loaded my project in Android Studio once again and let the gradle build finish.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by downgrading Android studio to version 4.1.3.
Before that I installed Node through NVM but it didn`t help

Comment: I also fixed the issue by downgrading Android studio to version 4.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

The real fix is stackoverflow.com/a/70891538/9878385

Run `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv` and this actually fixes the problem, rather than just working around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact error on a new MacBook M1 where I formerly used Java 8 with Rosetta (from the migration). After installing Zulu Java 8/11 with ARM-64bit support, I could not build the React Native App anymore.

I simply deleted the `.gradle` folder (e.g. in `~/.gradle`) and executed the build command again. It downloaded Gradle from scratch and the build worked.

Comment: I still had some problems, which were fixed with: updating Android gradle plugin to 4.2.2 and Gradle to 6.9.1. You can update those in File > Project Structure > Project

Answer (score 0):

Check Android Studio for available updates

`Android Studio -> Check For Updates`

I have updated Android Studio and Tools to the latest version and this solved the problem. Currently I have Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 (Build on April 28, 2022)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It could be some problem with permissions on Android Studio installation.

This might help you to open the project without this error, but it doesn't definitively solve the problem. (Ubuntu linux)

```
cd App_Name/android/
android-studio .
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same error using ReactNative and NVM. Installing NodeJS through package manager solved the problem. I guess NVM environment wasn't loaded in Android Studio environment.

Comment: Could you elaborate this in more detail? I installed nodejs via brew, but that didn't help either. Also rebooting did not help.

Comment: You can modify the NodeJS version by changing the executable/interpreter path in `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js`. That way, especially if you use `export NVM_SYMLINK_CURRENT=true` to make the `~/.nvm/current/` directory, Node will always be defined in your projects.

Docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-node-js-applications.html#ws_node_configure_local_node_interpreter